# Write and run node.js application in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I searched for this a day now and hope you can help me.

I really like developing JS Applications in TypeScript and I am trying to write my new node application that way. Unfortunately node does not understand TS. Is there a way (besides transpiling to ES5) to start my code directly from the TS file?

In the sad case there is no way to do that, what is the best practice? Writing the app in `src/ts/app.ts`, transpile it to `src/js/app.js` and reference this file in the `package.json`?

Comment: there is no way to run typescript on node without a transpiler. you could try systemjs and live transpiling but I'd advise against it.

Comment: You can use [TypeScript Node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) but why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 5):

Exactly. Simply run `tsc` before starting your node application. You typically do that by having something like this in your  `package.json`

```
{ ...
"main": "src/js/app.js",
"scripts": {
    "run": "tsc && node src/js/app.js"
}, ... }
```

For your further reference, there is a node sample from the official Typescript repositories [available here.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScriptSamples/tree/master/imageboard)